# Change text of button when pressing it ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the text of a button when I press it.

This is what I want to achieve: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010 , but I can't get my code to work (newbie).

```
class ObjectKeyDisplay extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      open: prevState.open
    }))
  }

  renderInner() {
      if (!this.props.value) return <td className = "inactive" > < /td>
      if (!this.state.open && this.props.schema.type === 'belongs_to')
      return <td onClick={(e) => this.setState({open: !this.state.open})}>
        <button onClick={this.handleCLick}>
          {this.state.open ? 'OFF' : 'ON'}
        </button>
      </td>
}
```

Here's my code and as you might have seen I want to toggle the text `OFF` and `ON` when pressing the button. I can add more code if needed. Really grateful for all the support I can get.

Comment: you forgot to use `!` here `open: !prevState.open` setting the same value again.

Comment: The second issue, is that you have the onClick in two places, this seams to be unnecessary

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, but I'm not so familiar how to do stuff in React.. @MayankShukla it didn't work :(

Comment: Shouldn't be it `render`?

Comment: The condition before return looks not stable.. for the task

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in handler:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  open: !prevState.open
}))
```

You are setting it to the same value, as it was before.. with `!bool` you can switch the value

Additionally the condition is not making any sense:

```
  if (!this.state.open && this.props.schema.type === 'belongs_to')
  return <td onClick={(e) => this.setState({open: !this.state.open})}>
    <button onClick={this.handleCLick}>
      {this.state.open ? 'OFF' : 'ON'}
    </button>
  </td>
```

This means only if the condition is met, you component will return something..

`true === (!this.state.open && this.props.schema.type === 'belongs_to')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
handleClick() {
    const open = !this.state.open;
    this.setState({open})
}
```